# Trouble launching mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I have some trouble using mysql on Ubuntu 12.04. I hope this post is in the right forum (if not, tell me where to move it)

When I run : sudo /etc/init.d/mysql, I get this message

```
Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
start: Job failed to start
```

When I run mysql -u root status, I get this

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

So I tried to kill the process, so I ran ps aux | grep mysql showing this

```
1000      3262  0.0  0.0   4388   832 pts/1    S+   14:05   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld
```

And when I run the kill command, I get this :

kill: No such process

When I launch sudo mysqld --verbose

```
[Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
121122 14:50:24 [ERROR] An old style --language value with language specific part detected: /usr/share/mysql/french/
121122 14:50:24 [ERROR] Use --lc-messages-dir without language specific part instead.
121122 14:50:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121122 14:50:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121122 14:50:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
121122 14:50:24 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
121122 14:50:24 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
121122 14:50:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121122 14:50:24 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121122 14:50:24  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121122 14:50:25 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 2289875
121122 14:50:25 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'
121122 14:50:25 [ERROR] Aborting

121122 14:50:25  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
121122 14:50:26  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2289875
121122 14:50:26 [Note] mysqld: Arrêt du serveur terminé
```

Could someone please help

Comment: Have you tried `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` ?

Comment: Sure here's what I got Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
start: Job failed to start

Comment: Time to dig into the error logs then, or run `sudo mysqld --verbose` from the command line to see what problems it reports.

Comment: Ok, I am going to fix some errors and warnings and the,n let you know what is going on !

Comment: @JeremySmyth, I edited my post, I changed my.cnf file but I keep on having the same message when I run sudo mysqld --verbose. It doesn't seem to take into account my changes. Perhaps it is now unable to load the new config again

Comment: Run `mysqld --verbose --help` and look for the line starting with "Default options...". It will tell you which `my.cnf` file your server is reading (although not always - `mysqld_safe` sometimes adds to that). You could try `locate my.cnf` to find which ones exist, and amalgamate their contents into a single file `/etc/my.cnf` to guarantee you know what options are used.

Comment: Ok, in fact I mislead because I fixed by hand all of the problems and I didn't know that default-character-set was deprecated. I changed it into character_set_server=utf8, and it worked perfectly ! Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the command "mysql", what you're trying to do is launch the mysql client.
Mysql client must connect to a server.
You should start mysql server, like Jeremy suggested, or using

```
sudo start mysql
```

See here for more information

https://askubuntu.com/questions/125686/mysql-fails-to-start-after-upgrade-to-12-04

Comment: Sure I tried it :) Here's what I get 'start: Job failed to start'

Comment: the askbuntu site seems to have a possible solution to your problem

Comment: Thank you I am going to check it !